# MediaWiki language bug still persists

Tags: debugging, translation, mediawiki, wiki

[image: English and German all mixed up]

This is on `en.myDomain.org`

This is in a logged out state on Chrome. As soon as i log in though, everything is in english, as it should be.

Same happens on firefox.

Anyone got any clue where this could stem from?

Comment: Still not getting anywhere. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you set the language in your user preferences to English.

To set the global language to English, change/put this in your LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgLanguageCode = "en";
```

Comment: No. I automatically always set `$wgLanguageCode` to the right value. I have also tested and confirmed it to be correct. What you see in the picture is definitly "en". I wish it was so easy.

Comment: Where do you see those German messages?
I can imagine that there's something wrong with your system messages (https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:System_message)

Comment: Thank you Stefahn! You are actually right. If i append `?uselang=en` to my URL everything is in english. How can i set this to ALWAYS be english on my `en.myDomain.org`?

Comment: We're getting there :)
Here's the link to your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994183/mediawiki-adjust-system-message-language

Comment: Do you know a solution @stefahn ?

Comment: I'm afraid no. The system messages should appear in the language you configured with $wgLanguageCode. Apparently they don't do this in your case...

Comment: I have been searching, but it seems there is no special attribute exclusively for system messages.

Comment: What happens if you change $wgLanguageCode to another language - do the system messages change their content (in my eyes they should) ?