# MediaWiki adjust system message language

Tags: translation, mediawiki, wiki, wikimedia

i had been having a bug, where my system messages are shown in the wrong language. I have got one simple question: How do i set the system message to always be e.g. `english` or `german` without adding `&uselang=de` to the URL. Is there a way to permanently change it in the local settings?

Comment: Do you want one system message, all system messages but just for you or all system messages for everybody to be in another language?

Comment: I want to change every system message for every user on my wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to change it in your file `LocalSettings.php`. For example, if you want to use Brazilian Portugese change it to:

```
$wgLanguageCode = 'pt-br';
```

For more info, see the manual: [Manual:$wgLanguageCode](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLanguageCode)

Comment: This is not the solution sadly. My `$wgLanguageCode` is always the correct one. I have tested this. The System messages may be in the wrong language anyway. See my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917625/mediawiki-language-bug-still-persists/34954425?noredirect=1#comment57755349_34954425

Comment: Hm, I guess then that your solution is [reporting the bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org) and wait until it get fixed properly.

Comment: I am using a custom skin and have added lots of custom elements to my wiki. It is possible, that the error stems from my alterations. Should i still report the bug?

Comment: Yes, report it. If it is due to your alterations the bug will be closed as invalid, but if not you have helped the Mediawiki community too.